# Transfer attachment to another testStep

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a REST test request that returns a MIME multipart/related message. One of the parts has type 'application/zip'.

In soapUi UI, I can see the zip file in the attachments tab.

1- I would like to have this file attached to the request of another REST testStep without manual intervention.

Is this possible with Groovy script ?

I guess it would start with :

```
def response = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName( "firstStep" ).testRequest.getResponse()
def firstStepAttachment = response1.attachments[0]
```

2- to make it a bit harder, the transfered file is a .zip and I'd like a specific file in it (I know its name and path), is there any way to do that during the file transfer?

Kudos